# How to create a simple slide Up slide down login/signup division in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

Hi i have ben pulling my hair out for about 24hours now with this code.

What i want to achieve is a simple Sign-in / Sign-Up option that will slide up and down the page and when the signup form is visible whenever i click on the signin the other form will hide and vice versa.

What happens with my code is that whenever I click on the signup or signin anchor that anchor disappears and the the form will just simply .()show it wont follow the slideup or down in the command but when i press the cancel button which i created an event to hide the form the animation of .slideUp() will push through and hide the form. and whenever i have a form visible lets say the signup, whenever i click on the sign in the 2 forms will be visible at the same time.

Can you please help me with this guys? Thank you very much!

**HTML**

```
<div id="divLinks">
    <div id="divNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="shop.html"> Shop</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="sell.html">Sell</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="divNavAccount">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="show_hide_sign_up">Not a user yet?</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="show_hide_sign_in">Sign In</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divSignIn" class="show_hide_sign_in">
    <div id="divSignInFields">
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="username">
            <br />
            <input type="password" name="password" value="password">
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="hideCancel">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="divSignInDescription">
        <ul>
            <li>Username:</li>
            <li>Password:</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divSignUp" class="show_hide_sign_up">
    <div id="divSignUpFields">
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="username">
            <br />
            <input type="password" name="password" value="password">
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="first name" value="first name">
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="last name" value="last name">
            <br/>
            <input type="email" name="email" value="user@email.com">
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="hideCancel2">
            <br/>
            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="divSignUpDescription">
        <ul>
            <li>Username:</li>
            <li>Password:</li>
            <li>First Name:</li>
            <li>Last Name:</li>
            <li>Email:</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .show_hide_sign_in {

    }

    .show_hide_sign_up {

    }

    .div_show_hide_sign_in {

    }

    .div_show_hide_sign_up {

    }

    .hideCancel {

    }

    .hideCancel2 {

    }
```

The bloody Jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#divSignIn").hide();

$('.show_hide_sign_in').click(function(){
    $(".show_hide_sign_in").slideUp().show();
$("#divSignIn").slideUp.show();

/*---hides the sign in form--*/
$("#divSignUp").hide();
/*---hides the sign in form--*/
    });


/*--cancel button--*/
$('.hideCancel').click(function(){
    $("#divSignIn").hide().slideDown();

    });
/*--cancel button--*/
});; 



/*sign up href sliding down*/
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#divSignIn").hide();


$('.show_hide_sign_in').click(function(){
    $(".show_hide_sign_in").slideUp().show();
$("#divSignIn").slideUp.show();

/*---hides the sign in form--*/
$("#divSignUp").hide();
/*---hides the sign in form--*/
    });


/*--cancel button--*/
$('.hideCancel').click(function(){
    $("#divSignIn").hide().slideDown();

    });
/*--cancel button--*/
});; 




/*sign up href sliding down*/
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#divSignUp").hide();


$('.show_hide_sign_up').click(function(){
    $(".show_hide_sign_up").slideUp().show();
$("#divSignUp").slideUp.show();

/*---hides the sign in form--*/
$("#divSignIn").hide();
/*---hides the sign in form--*/
    });


/*--cancel button--*/
$('.hideCancel2').click(function(){
    $("#divSignUp").hide().slideDown();

    });
/*--cancel button--*/
});;     
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#divSignIn").hide();


$('.show_hide_sign_in').click(function(){
    $(".show_hide_sign_in").slideUp().show();
$("#divSignIn").slideUp.show();

/*---hides the sign in form--*/
$("#divSignUp").hide();
/*---hides the sign in form--*/
    });


/*--cancel button--*/
$('.hideCancel').click(function(){
    $("#divSignIn").hide().slideDown();

    });
/*--cancel button--*/
});; 




/*sign up href sliding down*/
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#divSignUp").hide();

$('.show_hide_sign_up').click(function(){
    $(".show_hide_sign_up").slideUp().show();
$("#divSignUp").slideUp.show();

/*---hides the sign in form--*/
$("#divSignIn").hide();
/*---hides the sign in form--*/
    });


/*--cancel button--*/
$('.hideCancel2').click(function(){
    $("#divSignUp").hide().slideDown();

    });
/*--cancel button--*/
});;     
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#divSignIn").hide();

$('.show_hide_sign_in').click(function(){
    $(".show_hide_sign_in").slideUp().show();
$("#divSignIn").slideUp.show();

/*---hides the sign in form--*/
$("#divSignUp").hide();
/*---hides the sign in form--*/
    });


/*--cancel button--*/
$('.hideCancel').click(function(){
    $("#divSignIn").hide().slideDown();

    });
/*--cancel button--*/
});; 



    /*sign up href sliding down*/
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#divSignUp").hide();

$('.show_hide_sign_up').click(function(){
    $(".show_hide_sign_up").slideUp().show();
$("#divSignUp").slideUp.show();

/*---hides the sign in form--*/
$("#divSignIn").hide();
/*---hides the sign in form--*/
    });


/*--cancel button--*/
$('.hideCancel2').click(function(){
    $("#divSignUp").hide().slideDown();

    });
/*--cancel button--*/
});;     
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#divSignUp").hide();

$('.show_hide_sign_up').click(function(){
    $(".show_hide_sign_up").slideUp().show();
$("#divSignUp").slideUp.show();

/*---hides the sign in form--*/
$("#divSignIn").hide();
/*---hides the sign in form--*/
    });


/*--cancel button--*/
$('.hideCancel2').click(function(){
    $("#divSignUp").hide().slideDown();

    });
/*--cancel button--*/
});;
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? easier to see the problem

Comment: what's up with the empty css?

Comment: Please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: sorry guys i hope this is what your looking for

http://jsfiddle.net/mQqsP/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your show()'s and hide()'s to be called when the sliding is done. Like this:

```
    $(".show_hide_sign_up").slideUp(function() { $(this).show() } );
    $(".show_hide_sign_up").slideDown(function() { $(this).hide() } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well There Are Some Issues In Your Code That I'm Not Sure What's Their Point , Like :

1) '.slideUp().show();' and others similar .
2) Why Do Your toggller anchors and their toggled div's have the same name .

- For The First Issue I Assume that you wanted to check whether the target div is hidden OR is visible , if thats it Then you can use something like this :

  if ($("div.show_hide_sign_up").is(':hidden')) {

  ```
     $("div.show_hide_sign_up").slideDown(250);
  ```

  } else {

  ```
      $("div.show_hide_sign_up").slideUp(250);
  ```

  }
- For The Second One I Suggest to Use different class name to avoid conflicts between your html elements  , So Here We Are , I Think This code below would solve your problem

  $(document).ready(function (e) {

  ```
  $("#divSignIn").hide();

  $("#divSignUp").hide();

  $('a.show_hide_sign_in').click(function () {

      $("#divSignUp").slideUp(100);

      if ($("div.show_hide_sign_in").is(':hidden')) {

          $("div.show_hide_sign_in").slideDown(250);

      } else {

          $("div.show_hide_sign_in").slideUp(250);

      }

  });

  $('a.show_hide_sign_up').click(function () {

      $("#divSignIn").slideUp(100);

      if ($("div.show_hide_sign_up").is(':hidden')) {

          $("div.show_hide_sign_up").slideDown(250);

      } else {

          $("div.show_hide_sign_up").slideUp(250);

      }

  });


  $('.hideCancel').click(function () {

      $("#divSignIn").slideUp();

  });

  $('.hideCancel2').click(function () {

      $("#divSignUp").slideUp();

  });
  ```

  });

Comment: oh man thank you very much!!! this solved my problem ill definitely study this one! thanks thanks! Im taking up applications development and they discussed javascript 1 day only ha-ha thanks man! High five!

does this apply for the the .slide() Up and Down events only? I would assume with .hide and .show as well right?